# No results from SQL in C# when using GUID in where clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, guid, where-clause

I have a problem I cannot figure out. In my C# (VS) project I get results from my DB but not when using a WHERE-clause specifying a GUID value.

The SQLCommand below never returns any results, the query works on same computer for sqlcmd and it works on the DB server

```
SqlCommand blobSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT [DocumentData] FROM [archive].[dbo].[tbl] WHERE [Part.PartID] = '31A799AA-508D-4757-9DB5-167C2B75B197'", dataConnection);
```

This query returns results

```
SqlCommand blobSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT [DocumentData] FROM [archive].[dbo].[tbl]", dataConnection);
```

I can't figure out what is wrong.

EDIT:
To clear things up a bit this is the table:

```
Part.PartID                             DocumentData
31A799AA-508D-4757-9DB5-167C2B75B197    0x255044462...
717FE1D1-EEBF-46B5-8445-1A7CE0247C0F    0x255044462...
C04CCBB0-E2DC-4B94-911C-57571F6A04A6    0x255044462...
7F27C60C-3C29-42EE-9575-8E8B0E76BCE6    0x255044462...
```

Comment: have you executed the query in SSMS to see if there is any record with the value shown in your 1st query.

Comment: Checked that, the value exist in the table

Comment: Your query is the proper format for querying the GUID datatype in SQL. Is the column a Guid datatype? If it is, then I recommend double-checking your records.

Comment: This also works fine: D:\_temp\extract>bcp "SELECT [DocumentData] FROM [archive].[dbo].[tbl] WHERE [Part.PartID] = '31A799AA-508D-4757-9DB5-167C2B75B197'" queryout
 pdf.pdf -N -S 192.168.202.130 -U sa -P pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a GUID class in C#. If you store id in GUID object, and add it to your query using parameters, it might work.

Comment: Just tried this and I get the same result: SqlCommand blobSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT [DocumentData] FROM [archive].[dbo].[tbl] WHERE [Part.PartID] = @GUID", dataConnection);
                    Guid guid = new Guid("31A799AA-508D-4757-9DB5-167C2B75B197");
                    blobSQL.Parameters.Add("@GUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
                    blobSQL.Parameters["@GUID"].Value = guid;

Comment: Thats strange. You sure no exceptions are suppressed when you call your query? Btw do you execute it as scalar?

Comment: I believe not: SqlDataReader blobReader = blobSQL.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

Comment: What can I say. Run SQL Server Profiler (with TSQL template) to see what exactly is passed to MSSQL.

Comment: Don't know what to say...Now it works with this solution.
`SqlCommand blobSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT [DocumentData] FROM [archive].[dbo].[tbl] WHERE [Part.PartID] = @GUID", dataConnection);
                    Guid guid = new Guid("31A799AA-508D-4757-9DB5-167C2B75B197");
                    blobSQL.Parameters.Add("@GUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
                    blobSQL.Parameters["@GUID"].Value = guid;`